# How to view and kill PHP processes?

Tags: linux, ssh, shell

I'm very new to using SSH and am having trouble finding a way to view and kill PHP processes that are running.

When I say "PHP processes," I mean PHP files that were started through the browser, but that have continued to run when they were supposed to stop.

I tried this:

```
ps aux | grep php
```

But there aren't any results, even though I know the files are running.

How can I view the files that are running and then selectively kill them (or kill them all)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Htop can be used to view processes and selectively kill them:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

As ckujau said, it depends on your setup, but typically a new php process is spawned by apache and lives for the  duration of a request. In htop, inspect apache while making a request. A php process should start. If it stays alive, you can select and kill it.

Here's a screenshot of htop showing php-fpm processes. php-fpm maintains a pool of long running php processes, able to be reused for multiple requests.

Note 'htop' is a more user friendly version of 'top'.

See also htop explained: https://peteris.rocks/blog/htop/

[image]

Comment: How do you get it to just show php processes?

Comment: Filter by pressing F4 or \ key and typing the text you want to filter by.

Comment: Display as 'Tree' by pressing F5 or t. This shows the hierarchy of processes and forked child process. Sending a terminate signal to a process will usually also terminate it's child processes.

Answer (score 2):

The "php files", that is the program files ending in `.php` may not be visible with `ps`. But `ps` may be able to display the machinery that will in turn run those `.php` files. Depending on your setup this could be managed via [fast-cgi or mod_php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953793/mod-php-vs-cgi-vs-fast-cgi) or even [php-fpm](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php). If you use `mod_php`, then there will be no "php processes" visible for `ps`. You can still see if your PHP engine is in use by using `lsof`:

```
$ lsof -ln
[...]
```